# Could Not Start Pub Server Or Connect To Pub

Tags: eclipse, dart, server, dart-pub

I have installed Dart Environment for Eclipse, and i've done some simple project. But today, i create new Dart project and start with it. But it show error:

[image: Error]

I try to run my old projects. But it make same error like this.

```
Unhandled exception: Load Error for "package:barback/barback.dart":
Failure getting http://localhost:52437/packages/barback/barback.dart: 
404 Not Found
#0      _asyncLoadErrorCallback (dart:_builtin:116)
#1      _asyncLoadError (dart:_builtin:348)
#2      _handleLoaderReply (dart:_builtin:292)
#3      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:148)
dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart 357  Isolate._spawnUri
dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart 313  Isolate.spawnUri
package:pub/src/dart.dart 215              _isolateBuffer
dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart 264  _startIsolate.<fn>
dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart 148 
_RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage
```

How can i sovle it? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please add all error output from the console window to your question?

Comment: I  hoped there was more information. Can you please run `pub serve --verbose` from the command line from your project directory and add the output?  What Dart version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Dart version 1.11.1

Comment: And here all log when i run pub serve --verbose:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1R4-0_fQ8APUqljMP8WfCjxKFvpF_7UTtan9di48K6E0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Do this barback and html5lib files exist in your `packages` subdirectory. Did you run `pub get` or `pub upgrade`?

Comment: What does this mean? After `pub get`/`pub upgrade`? Have you checked if the files mentioned in the `pub serve --verbose` log actually exist ( `packages/barback/barback.dart`, `packages/html5lib/dom.dart`, `/packages/html5lib/parser.dart`)? You can also try `pub cache repair`.

Comment: I try to run command <code>pub cache repair</code>. It re download all pub package. Then i open my eclipse, run my project and it can run again. But my project explorer show like this: http://imgur.com/JZGgSn6. Can i remove all this package? Anyway, thanks you for your support. :)

Comment: This looks fine, why do you want to remove the packages? You still get the error "Could Not Start Pub Server Or Connect To Pub"?

Comment: Thanks, i don't have any error when run my project. But it make not clean on my project explorer. :)

Answer (score 1):

While I realize this question was from a year ago, I did run into the same issue just recently, and found I had to manually delete the entire pub cache - as if the cache had become corrupted.

I just `cd` over to the pub cache dir and deleted everything, so a new `pub get` would re-get it all.

At least on mac, the pub cache dir is `~/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/`.

Comment: Next time you can give `pub cache repair` a try before you delete the cache. Occasionally purging the cache doesn't hurt though.

Comment: Didn't know about `cache repair` until recently, but agreed its easier!